# Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using LINQ in my project and my code is:

```
var SE = from c in Shop.Sections
                    join c1 in obj.SectionObjects on c.SectionId equals c1.SectionId
                    select c;

 dataGridView1.DataSource = SE;
```

but I face this error in line `dataGridView1.DataSource = SE;`
error message is:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.

Comment: Hover over the Shop.Sections and tell us its type.
Then hover over obj.SectionObjects and tell us its type.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can't use a Join between a SQL source and a local source.  You'll need to bring the SQL data into memory before you can join them.  In this case, you're not really doing a join since you only take the elements from the first collection, what you want is a *select...where...selectid in* query, which you can get using the Contains method.

```
 var SE = Shop.Sections.Where( s => obj.SectionObjects
                                       .Select( so => so.SectionId )
                                       .Contains( s.SectionId ))
                       .ToList();
```

Translates to

```
select * from Sections where sectionId in (...)
```

where the values for the in clause come from the list of ids in the collection of local objects.

Comment: It's not quite true. It's possible to use join if a local source goes first. See answer below.

Answer (score 33):

You can't join local source to SQL source,
but you CAN join SQL source to local, v.v.

```
var SE = from c1 in obj.SectionObjects
              join c in Shop.Sections on c1.SectionId equals c.SectionId
              select c;
```

In other words, local source must come first

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. In this approach, (unless I'm deeply mistaken), the SQL source will not be enumerated (hence avoiding some DB overhead)

Comment: This solution works if the db table is rather small.  However, it DOES enumerate the entire table from the DB to memory (verified with SQL Trace) to do the comparison.  We had a complex multi-table "SQL source to local" scenario and started getting an out of memory exception error as a result.  The other answers using contains allows the query to run on the SQL Server using "IN" and only pulls the related records.  Those answer should be the accepted answer, especially for larger tables.

Answer (score 12):

This should work and be done on the database side (using `IN`), rather than in memory:

```
var SE = from c in Shop.Sections 
        where obj.SectionObjects.Select(z => z.SectionId).Contains(c.SectionId)
        select c;
```

[L2S Profiler](http://l2sprof.com/) is very helpful for these kinds of things - you can compare the different SQL being generated by my solution and other solutions.

Comment: this code in invalid, error is: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<Shop.SectionObject>.Contains(Shop.SectionObject)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Yeah, it looks like L2S is basically dead - https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqToSqlProfiler

Comment: on database side is much faster than in memory!

Answer (score -5):

var SE = from c in Shop.Sections.AsEnumerable().ToList()
                    join c1 in obj.SectionObjects.AsEnumerable().ToList() on c.SectionId equals c1.SectionId
                    select c;

dataGridView1.DataSource = SE;