# Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

I am getting this error from the below linq query:

```
List<Something> results = new List<Something>(items
.Where(w => selecteditems.Count == 0 || w.ops.Intersect(selecteditems).Count() > 0)
.ToList()
.OrderBy(a => a.FirstNumber)
.OrderBy(b => b.SecondNumber));
```

Would the intersect be throwing this error?

Comment: Take a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164460/local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementation-of-query-operators-e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query provider doesn't know how to translate `w.ops.Intersect(selecteditems)` into a SQL query.

If `selecteditems` was another query from the same query provider then it may be able to translate them, or if the entire operation were being done in Linq-to-Objects, rather than Linq-to-SQL, then it would be fine.

As per the error message, the only operation it knows how to perform on such an object is `Contains`.  You can re-work your query to use that instead:

```
.Where(w => selecteditems.Count == 0 || 
    w.ops.Any(op => selecteditems.Contains(op)))
```

That [should] work.