# Use Contains when list having more than one field

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using two views both are placed on different databases(on different SERVERS). I am getting records from both and i have to use full outer join functionality in LINQ (I know LINQ not support Full Outer Join) to get all records whether they are matching or not.

For this i am using the following code snippet

**Call for View1:**

```
var specialRequest = (from specialReq in dc1.View1
                     select specialReq).ToList();
```

This view returning more than one field, and i need all of them.

**Call for View2 and Join with View1 result:**

```
 var SummaryDataLeftOuter = (
    from specialReq in specialRequest
    join summary in dc.View2 on specialReq.inv_item_id equals summary.inv_item_id
    into tempspecialReq
    from summary in tempspecialReq.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Summary
        {
            inv_item_id = string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialReq.inv_item_id) ? "" : specialReq.inv_item_id.Contains("NO ITEM NUMBER") ? "NO PART #" : specialReq.inv_item_id,
            description = specialReq.description,
            unit_of_measure = specialReq.unit_of_measure,
            total_onorder_qty = (specialReq.TotalOrder.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(specialReq.TotalOrder) : 0) + (summary == null ? 0 : summary.TotalOrder.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(summary.TotalOrder) : 0),
            open_order_qty = (specialReq.TotalOpen.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(specialReq.TotalOpen) : 0) + (summary == null ? 0 : summary.OpenOrder.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(summary.OpenOrder) : 0),
            picked_qty = summary == null ? 0 : summary.PickedQty.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(summary.PickedQty) : 0,
            qty_shipped = summary == null ? 0 : summary.qty_shipped.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(summary.qty_shipped) : 0,
            EnableLink = string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialReq.inv_item_id) ? false : specialReq.inv_item_id.Contains("NO ITEM NUMBER") ? false : true
        }
).ToList();
```

**Use Join again after changing the table order:**

```
var SummaryDataRightOuter = (
    from summary in dc.View2
    join specialReq in specialRequest on summary.inv_item_id equals specialReq.inv_item_id
    into tempsummary
    from specialReq in tempsummary.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Summary
        {
            inv_item_id = string.IsNullOrEmpty(summary.inv_item_id) ? "" : summary.inv_item_id.Contains("NO ITEM NUMBER") ? "NO PART #" : summary.inv_item_id,
            description = summary.descr60,
            unit_of_measure = summary.unit_of_measure,
            total_onorder_qty = specialReq == null ? 0 : (specialReq.TotalOrder.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(specialReq.TotalOrder) : 0) + (summary == null ? 0 : summary.TotalOrder.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(summary.TotalOrder) : 0),
            open_order_qty = specialReq == null ? 0 : (specialReq.TotalOpen.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(specialReq.TotalOpen) : 0) + (summary == null ? 0 : summary.OpenOrder.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(summary.OpenOrder) : 0),
            picked_qty = summary == null ? 0 : summary.PickedQty.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(summary.PickedQty) : 0,
            qty_shipped = summary == null ? 0 : summary.qty_shipped.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(summary.qty_shipped) : 0,
            EnableLink = specialReq == null ? false : string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialReq.inv_item_id) ? false : specialReq.inv_item_id.Contains("NO ITEM NUMBER") ? false : true
        }
);
```

**Now on second call i am getting the following Exception :**

```
  Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator
```

I already searched a lot on web and got many solution all of them saying to use Contains. But all of them giving example in which first list i.e specialRequest contains only one column e.g [One example you can check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164460/local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementation-of-query-operators-e). But i require all columns.

**Problem :**

How to use Contains() when list having more than one field.

Answer (score 0):

As in my question you are seeing that i am directly using view2 in join without assigning it in any list. This is the main reason of the problem.

**Solution :**

First assign view result into list and then use this list for further process.