# Linq with String Array Contains

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a string array of items & a list of database objects and I want to do a select query out of it

```
List<string> target_terms = new List<string> { "car", "mechanic" }

if (isNotExactPhrase)
{
    List<int> _tagIds = (from item in dbContext.Tags
                    where target_terms.Any(w => item.TagName.Contains(w))
                    select item.TagId).ToList();
}
```

I want all tags with names in the array

I have to use 2 options I want to check Tagname contains any of the keyword &
If search is for exact phrase then I want to check any of the Tagname == any of the keyword

But for this query I am getting error

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator.

How to solve this?

Comment: Your code does not even compile at the first line..

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164460/local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementation-of-query-operators-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
var _tagIds = (from item in dbContext.Tags
                    where keywords.contains(item.TagName)
                    select item.TagId).ToList();
```

There's no direct equivalent, but there are some methods work similarly, depending on the pattern.

string.Contains("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE '%pattern%'

string.StartsWith("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE 'pattern%'

string.EndsWith("pattern") is equivalent to LIKE '%pattern'

Comment: This one worked but when i try to use another Linq Qury with this _tagIds its showing the same error

Comment: Now check what is return.

Comment: How can i do the second case . Instead of using contains how can i check with  == . Since if the user search for "car"  and if there is a tag exists with word "carmel" that item will also be included

Comment: The Author tried to compare tags by substring. That is not the answer. (Author's Case: tag = "super_code", keyword = "er_co" ... your query will not return that as a result).

Answer (score 1):

After hitting this problem a multitude of times, I created a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/) that solves this common issue.

Using [NinjaNye.SearchExtensions](http://ninjanye.github.io/SearchExtensions/stringsearch.html) you can do the following:

```
var _tagIds = dbContext.Tags.Search(t => t.TagName)
                            .Containing(keywords)
                            .Select(t => t.TagId)
                            .ToList();
```

If you needed to you could also search against multiple properties and return records where a match was found in either property.

```
var _tagIds = dbContext.Tags.Search(t => t.TagName, t => t.Description)
                            .Containing(keywords)
                            .Select(t => t.TagId)
                            .ToList();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `Any` with `contains`

```
List<int> _tagIds = (from item in dbContext.Tags
                    where target_terms.Contains(w => item.TagName.Contains(w))
                    select item.TagId).ToList();
```

Comment: I think Second contains should not be there if you are using target_terms.contains