# Linq to SQL any from Enumerable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm working on a search engine for our application.
The User should be able to find the item containing more words, or any of those words. The User can use "find where contains all words" or "find where contains any word".

I am using C# 4.6.2 and LINQ to SQL.

code is something like:

```
var words = userInput.Split(' '); // can be something like "Hi all"
var result = selection.Where(q => words.Any(k => q.Name.Contains(k)));
```

In this case the user wants to find items that contain "Hi" or "all"

When I try iterate through result, I get this exception:
Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator

Do you have any idea what is best approach?

Thank you
Jakub

Comment: Searching the error message on SO tends to produce better results: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8164460/335858

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164460/local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementation-of-query-operators-e)

Comment: You might consider using full text indexing feature of MSSQL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the suggested solutions, and I prefer to search at the server side. So I decide to use an expression tree to create robust queries.

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Address), "findingSource");
Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, "Name");
Expression right = Expression.Constant(words[0]);
MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
Expression expression = Expression.Call(left, method, right);
var result = expression;

for (var i = 1; i < words.Count; i++)
{
    left = Expression.Property(pe, "Name");
    right = Expression.Constant(words[i]);
    method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    expression = Expression.Call(left, method, right);

    result = Expression.OrElse(result, expression);
}

MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { selection.ElementType },
    selection.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Address, bool>>(result, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

return selection.Provider.CreateQuery<Address>(whereCallExpression);
```