# Cannot convert Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

So for a assignement I got I have to convert the data I get through an API into a  object and save that object in the database. Since the object doesn't have a any property that is unique there are multiple primary key columns in my database.

So what I basically have to do is a 'merge' from to my database so if data has been changed to a update if data is new do an insert. For some reason one my linq queries for this is giving an error.

**My database:**
[image: Database]

**My Code:**

```
 public void Insert(List<MEDSU1> medsu1s)
        {
            var keys = medsu1s.Select(y => new { SUPP = y.S1SUPP?.Trim() ?? null, COMP = y.S1COMP?.Trim() ??null }).ToList();
            List<MEDSU1> medusFromSql = MediusDataContext.MEDSU1s.Where(y =>
                keys.Any(z => z.SUPP == y.S1SUPP && z.COMP == y.S1COMP)).ToList();


            var toUpdate = from medsu1org in MediusDataContext.MEDSU1s 


                join sqlkeys in medusFromSql
                    on new
                    {
                        aa = medsu1org.S1COMP,
                        bb = medsu1org.S1SUPP
                    }
                    equals
                    new
                    {
                        aa = sqlkeys.S1COMP,
                        bb = sqlkeys.S1SUPP
                    } 
                select new
                {
                    sql = medsu1org,
                    obj = sqlkeys,
                };



            toUpdate.ToList().ForEach(y =>
                        {
                            y.obj.S1COMP= y.sql.S1COMP;
                            y.obj.S1SUPP = y.sql.S1SUPP;
                            y.obj.S1SUNA = y.sql.S1SUNA;
                            y.obj.S1BAAC = y.sql.S1BAAC;
                            y.obj.S1VATN = y.sql.S1VATN;
                            y.obj.S1COUN = y.sql.S1COUN;
                            y.obj.S1PREF = y.sql.S1PREF;
                            y.obj.S1TAXD = y.sql.S1TAXD;
                            y.obj.S1CURR = y.sql.S1CURR;
                            y.obj.S1TYPE = y.sql.S1TYPE;
                            y.obj.S1ACNR = y.sql.S1ACNR;
                            y.obj.S1ACNM = y.sql.S1ACNM;
                            y.obj.S1EINV = y.sql.S1EINV;
                            y.obj.S1DLAY = y.sql.S1DLAY;
                            y.obj.S1TERM = y.sql.S1TERM;
                            y.obj.S1PYEE = y.sql.S1PYEE;
                        });
            var toInsert = medsu1s.Except(toUpdate.Select(y => y.obj)).ToList();
            MediusDataContext.MEDSU1s.InsertAllOnSubmit(toInsert);
            MediusDataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The part of the code that is giving me the error is the:

```
   var keys = medsu1s.Select(y => new { SUPP = y.S1SUPP?.Trim() ?? null, COMP = y.S1COMP?.Trim() ??null }).ToList();
   List<MEDSU1> medusFromSql = MediusDataContext.MEDSU1s.Where(y =>
                        keys.Any(z => z.SUPP == y.S1SUPP && z.COMP == y.S1COMP)).ToList();
```

I think it has to do with me using .Any incorrectly and converting it to a List but i dont know to fix it. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

ERROR im getting : "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: Read [ask] and include the error as well as your research into your question.

Comment: `For some reason one my linq queries for this is giving an error.` Any clues as to the error?

Comment: Added the error to the post. Sorry totally forgot

Comment: Try following : List<MEDSU1> medusFromSql = MediusDataContext.MEDSU1s.Where(y =>
                        keys.Any(z => z.SUPP == y.S1SUPP && z.COMP == y.S1COMP)).Select(x => new MEDSU1() {add the class properties here s1comp = x.Field<string>("S1Comp") }).ToList();

Comment: `?? null` is kinda pointless because that literally means "if it's null then replace with null"

Comment: The error message litterally tells you to use `Contains` instead of `Any`.  Have you tried that?  Though with a compound key you might have to create the query with a foreach over the keys and doing one `Where` for each one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164460/local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementation-of-query-operators-e)

Comment: @juharr I have tried using contains but game me more errors then with the use of any. Will try to use it again

Comment: @mjwills That question involved a join one one column/property.  This involves 2 which I think makes this a slightly different question.

Comment: @PedroLopes I was afraid `Contains` wouldn't work.  I think you'll have to generate the condition procedurally.  But it's not as straight forward as I originally thought as you basically want a bunch of `S1SUPP == @Key1Col1 && S1COMP == @Key1Col2` or'ed together.

Comment: @mjwills Who said there has to be a duplicate?  I'm just pointing out that I don't think that duplicate applies.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @juharr .

Comment: @juharr Yes that is what I want to do with this statement. Is there an easier way for me to achieve a "merge" in c#code that I maybe could use instead of my above code?

Comment: @PedroLopes Well a `AsEnumerable` before the `Where` will make this run in memory instead of trying to generate SQL.  The down side to that is it will pull all the rows in your table.  So I'd only consider doing that if the number of rows isn't large as it could be a major performance hit.

Comment: @juharr I'm afraid this wont be possible for me then. since there are over the 100 000 objects i have to store in my database.

Comment: I'm thinking what you'll want is to build the expression.  I haven't had to do that before so I'll have to research a bit to give you an answer.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries

Comment: Consider changing `var keys = medsu1s.Select(y => new { SUPP = y.S1SUPP?.Trim() ?? null, COMP = y.S1COMP?.Trim() ??null }).ToList();` to instead **concatenate** the two strings (with a separator like ~). Then use `Contains` against that. It isn't pretty (since you will lose benefits of database indexes etc) but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with a compound key you'll have to create a query that basically looks like

```
Select *
From MEDSU1s
Where (S1SUPP == @S1SUPP1 && S1COMP == @S1COMP1)
    OR (S1SUPP == @S1SUPP2 && S1COMP == @S1COMP2)
    OR ....
```

To do that with Linq you'd have to build the expression procedurally.  Note that I'm assuming the columns are both strings, so change the type of them as needed.  Also I have no good way of testing this out but hopefully this can get you started towards a solution.

```
var queryableData = MediusDataContext.MEDSU1s;

var table = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MEDSU1s), "x");

var suppCol = Expression.Property(table, typeof(string), "S1SUPP");
var compCol = Expression.Property(table, typeof(string), "S1COMP");

Expression condition = Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(0));
foreach (var x in keys)
{
    var key1 = Expression.Equal(suppCol, Expression.Constant(x.SUPP));
    var key2 = Expression.Equal(compCol, Expression.Constant(x.COMP));
    var both = Expression.AndAlso(key1, key2);
    condition = Expression.OrElse(condition, both);
}

var whereExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
    queryableData.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<MEDSU1s, bool>>(
        condition, 
        new ParameterExpression[] { table }));

var medusFromSql = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<MEDSU1s>(whereExpression).ToList();
```

Comment: Your SQL example just has the same condition repeated twice?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of parameters that can be used with this technique?

Comment: @NetMage Yeah, fixed that.

Comment: @mjwills Well SQL Server has a parameter limit of 2,100.