# How to do a dynamic Where clause Comparison over a List of Strings in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Editing my question:

```
IQueryable<dbJob> dbjobs = from a in TableA
                           join b in TableB on a.ID equals b.ID
                           where a.Attribute == X && 
                                 a.Attribute == Y &&
                                 a.Attribute  == Z
                           select b;
```

This is the base query and it works fine. I want to similar query but instead of hardcoded values (X, Y and Z) I have string list and list size can be 1, 2 or 3 or 10.

Comment: Just check if `a.Attribute` is _contained_ in your list...  You also might want to consider using method syntax for things like this, it makes it _much_ easier to read and fits the language better

Comment: shouldn't it be or?

Comment: When you do Contains, its an OR. I wanted AND

Comment: "When you do Contains, its an OR. I wanted AND" How can a string be multiple strings? Let's say your attribute is "steve" and your list of strings is "steve", "sally", "heather". Checking `"steve" == "steve" && "steve" == "sally" && "steve" == "heather"` makes no sense. Your attribute can't match multiple strings in your list unless your list of strings is a bunch of duplicates, but then what's the point of the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164460/local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementation-of-query-operators-e)

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is to create a validation method that takes the two lists as a parameters and do the comparisons then return true or false, and then use it in the where clause.